# Computing total road length in fixed radius circle around a point

Tags: qgis, road, length

I have a dataset of a number of points which are plotted on QGIS using their latitude and longitude. Now, I have to find out the total length of roads surrounding each point within a circle of radius, say 100m.

This feature comprising of total road length surrounding each point in a buffer radius is further to be used for land-use regression.

Can someone suggest on how to obtain this feature?

Comment: Tried to buffer the points, clip the roads using the buffer and use field calculator to compute line length of the clipping result?

Comment: Yes, I did that and it worked, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you prepare a buffer of your points with "vector > geoprocessing > buffer" and define 100 m as the buffer distance, leave every other option as is; after that
there's a function just for that in "vector > analysis tools > sum line length", use your buffers and your lines as parameters;
according to the manual:
Sum line lengths
This algorithm takes a polygon layer and a line layer and measures the total length of lines and the total number of them that cross each polygon.
The resulting layer has the same features as the input polygon layer, but with two additional attributes containing the length and count of the lines across each polygon. The names of these two fields can be configured in the algorithm parameters.

Comment: don't forget to reproject the base data into a projection in metres or you will end up with the whole world in 100 degrees of the point.

Comment: Thanks Elio! It worked, also, thanks Ian, I projected it in meters and then processed it. :)

Comment: If it worked you may mark the answer as accepted, this helps other users find their way through all possible answers